# posting to database via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js function to update the database according to values from the select input fields.
This is the javascript function:

```
            function getStatusAction()
            {
              var matchId = $(this).attr('match-id');
              var status = jQuery('#match-status').val();
              jQuery.ajax({
                url:'../core/match_stat.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{matchId:matchId,status:status},
                success: function(data){
                    //alert("Ok");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error..");
                },
              });
            }
            jQuery('select[name="match-status"]').change(getStatusAction);
```

Part of the html:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="input" name="match-status" match-id="<?=$ActiveMatch['id'];?>" id="match-status">
                            <option value="3" <?= (($ActiveMatch['status'] == '3')?'selected':'')?>> </option>
                            <option value="1" <?= (($ActiveMatch['status'] == '1')?'selected':'');?> >won</option>
                            <option value="2" <?= (($ActiveMatch['status'] == '2')?'selected':'');?> >lost</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

The function is supposed to get the id of the match eg 1,2... and the status eg 1,2,3 for loose, win and default status respectively.
The problem is I can only update the first row of data. If I try doing so on another row of data, the values from the first call are used. For example if I update first row status to win, if I try updating second row to loose it is updated to win. The status of the previous operation.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
        function getStatusAction(Element)  //<< add parameter here 
        {
          var matchId = $(Element).attr('match-id');  // <<< use it here
          var status = jQuery('#match-status').val();
          jQuery.ajax({
            url:'../core/match_stat.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{matchId:matchId,status:status},
            success: function(data){
                //alert("Ok");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error..");
            },
          });
        }
        jQuery('select[name="match-status"]').on('change' , function(){
           getStatusAction(this);  // << use the function here
        });
```

Note: **id should be unique** so if you have only one element with id `match-status` its fine .. but if your `select`s have the same id  you need to change `id="match-status"` to `class="match-status"` and change `var status = jQuery('#match-status').val();` to `var status = $(Element).val();`